# Smack 4.1.8 Failed resolution of: Lorg/jivesoftware/smack/tcp/XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration;

Tags: smack

I am building a Smack client using 4.1.8 library. The code compiles fine. When I run, the app crashes with the error :
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/jivesoftware/smack/tcp/XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration;

My import lines :

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.*;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.iqregister.AccountManager;
```

app Gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile group: 'org.igniterealtime.smack', name: 'smack-extensions',     version: '4.1.8'
    compile group: 'org.igniterealtime.smack', name: 'smack-java7', version: '4.1.8'
    compile group: 'org.igniterealtime.smack', name: 'smack-tcp', version: '4.1.8'
    compile group: 'org.igniterealtime.smack', name: 'smack-core', version: '4.1.8'}
```

project gradle

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

I tried putting the smack files in the lib folder as well, but get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

you required add more dependency in your gradle it work for me.

```
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.8"

compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.8"

compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-core:4.1.8"

compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.8"

compile "org.jxmpp:jxmpp-jid:0.5.0-alpha6"

compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.1.8"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modify your dependency:

```
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.8"
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.8"
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.8"
```